# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," - React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this message error, this never happened before...
I'm comparing to a code and it's exactly like that and it's not showing any error.

My Code:

```
interface AuthState {
  token: string;
  user: User;
}

interface SignInCredentials {
  login: string;
  senha: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  login: string;
}

interface AuthContextData {
  user: User;
  token: string;
  signIn(credentials: SignInCredentials): Promise<void>;
  signOut(): void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData);

const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AuthState>(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('@Ponteflix:token');
    const user = localStorage.getItem('@Ponteflix:user');

    if (token && user) {
      return { token, user: JSON.parse(user) };
    }

    return {} as AuthState;
  });
```

Can soomeone help me?

Img:

[image]

Comment: Is typescript installed ? Naive question, but I had to ask it aha

Comment: `const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextData);` should work

Comment: Doens't worked.
And yes, typescript is installed

Comment: That is weird. For me everything works.

Comment: That's strange.  I get errors like that sometimes but it's when I'm declaring a generic rather than setting one.  I don't know why you are getting it at this particular place in your code.  It has to do with it being a `.tsx` file rather than `.ts` so typescript sees `<AuthContextData>` as a JSX code and gets confused.  But again, that doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a ESLint problem, I solved including `eslintrc.json` inside project root with it's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, should the  `AuthContextData` should be the return type?

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>(): AuthContextData;
```

Comment: `{} as AuthContextData` is a valid syntax. Similar to saying `const ac = {} as AuthContextData; somefunctionThatTakesAuthContext(ac)`

Comment: It doesn't worked.
I'm shure that's a valid syntax. I used it once. 
This error is the first time.

Comment: @Nishant Does it has a specific name?